# Python 3.7.4: encoding issues with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable in a python file that contains a string. When I reference this variable in the same file all goes well, though if the values are stored in an .ini file instead, and referenced via  `ConfigParser.ConfigParser()` et al, the string comes back with double quotes around it. It is still of the data type `str`, though they are no longer the same.

As an example.

```
firstName = "Eli"
print(firstName) # Eli

myParser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
myParser.read("config.ini")

myFirstName = myParser.get("Names","firstName")
print(myFirstName) # "Eli"
```

the comments above show what the output would be. I'd like to be able to get the latter approach (from the .ini file) to either return the string sans double quotes, or a way to get them out (replace doesn't work). My guess is that it has something to do with encoding, though I cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Here's what my config.ini file looks like

```
[Names]
firstName = "Eli"
...
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with encoding. What's in `config.ini`?

Comment: @Chris I'll add the config.ini content into the question

Comment: `myParser.get("Names","firstName").strip('"')`

Comment: There are quotes in your file. If you don't want them, don't include them. Why are they there?

Comment: @wpercy that worked, though as the others pointed out since it isn't code, there was no need for the quotes there. I think that I'll take that approach. Thanks for your input

Comment: @chris I initially had them inside the python file, though I moved them to the .ini file as-is. I should have figured that once it isn't in code, there's no need for me to enclose them in quotes. thank you!

Comment: why can't you not use double quotes in .ini file?

Comment: @Sha it's not that you can't; rather, if I had `"Eli"` in my .ini file it would be akin to having a string in Python as `""Eli""`

Comment: @Eli, which version of the python you are using ?

Comment: @Sha 3.7.4, I put it in the question title

Comment: Try on python 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mistake:

```
[Names]
firstName = "Eli"
...
```

You put quotes around the string, therefore you are getting quotes. Config files are plain text, it's not a programming language where you have to differentiate between strings and other data types.

Now I'm not sure why replace doesn't work.